# iOS optimize image download speed from own server

Tags: ios, performance, optimization, uiimage, nsurlconnection

I have a gallery and detailed view controllers in my application, when a user taps a thumbnail in the gallery I redirect them to the detailed controller and begin to asynchronously download original-sized image, which is 640x640 px and it takes like 5-6 seconds to download. Is there a way to optimize the image download speed?

For example Instagram does this in around 0.2-1.0 second, like incredibly fast. My thinking is that they use some kickass compression on the server side and then unarchive the image they got in the Application. Are there any ways to do something like that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which file format are you currently using to store the images?

Comment: Do you download image from network? Also if you set image on non main thread it's slow. Show code for the image loading.

Comment: I do download the image from network, really it's pretty obvious since I wrote that in the title of the question. Setting/rendering image on non-main thread is impossible. My image loading code is irrelevant to the question, please read my question thoroughly if you really wish to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, I had to change the image format to .jpeg from .png, the compression rate of 40%, the quality is pretty good and the image size changed to 45kb from 600kb, which increased the speed.